# Using XPath to select an element in XSD file always returns an empty list

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have an XSD file as below. And I want to select the node `xs:element` based on its attribute value `name=content`. I use the code below to get that element, but it always returns an empty list.

```
String strBuiltinSchema = new String(schemaContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(strBuiltinSchema)));

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

String expression = "//xs:element[@name='myapp']//xs:element[@name='content']";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
// nodeList is always empty...
```

And here is my input XSD file.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/nxsd/surrogate/request"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/nxsd/surrogate/request"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="myapp">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="content">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="EmployeeID" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="EName" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="attribute">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="item" type="xs:integer" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>                        
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is its XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myapp>
  <content>
    <EmployeeID>7856932</EmployeeID>
    <EName>John William</EName>
  </content>
  <attribute>
    <item>3922</item>
  </attribute>
</myapp>
```

Comment: can you post the XML? Is it valid?

Comment: No, I want to find a node from the input XSD file and then append some child nodes for it. I don't do the validation task against any XML files.

Comment: BTW, I have updated the XML Schema as you request

Comment: sorry, my mistake! It think the xpath expression is fine. Maybe it's the *java-part*? Did you try to debug what's in `doc`?

Comment: The ```doc``` is correct. When I call ```doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("element")```, I can see its ```nodeCount=6```

Comment: Could you try to insert `builder.setNamespaceAware(true)` and check again?

Comment: Apart from the problems noted with namespaces, please do be aware that writing XPath like this to access a schema is terribly fragile; your code will easily break if someone decides to write the schema in a different coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Remove `xs:` from the XPath expression *(simple, but not recommended)*:

   ```java
   String expression = "//element[@name='myapp']//element[@name='content']";
   ```

   See demo on [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hJtiR8).
2. Enable namespaces:

   ```java
   factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
   ```

   ```java
   xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
       @Override
       public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
           switch (prefix) {
               case "xs": return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
               default:   return null;
           }
       }
       @Override
       public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
       @Override
       public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
   });
   ```

   See demo on [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/824Wxl).

Comment: hmm, I have tried those two options. But, they also return the empty list.

Comment: @NoName Really? Here is your code, except the schema has been inlined, with *both `xs:` removed* from the XPath expression, and it finds one `Node`: [Option 1 Solution](https://ideone.com/hJtiR8). --- And here your code is again, with *namespace enabled*, also finding one `Node`: [Option 2 Solution](https://ideone.com/824Wxl). --- I actually tested the code in the answer before posting it. Don't know what you tried, because both options work.

Comment: +1 for option #2: Enabling namespaces is the correct solution;  -1 for option #1: It's a hack that disregards the fact that those elements *are* in a namespace special to XSDs; +1 for the solid demos in a follow-up comment.  Net: +1.   ;-)

Comment: @Andreas: Your solution is correct! But, as I mentioned, it does not work in my context because of another issue happening right before calling my method. After I fix that issue, it works now! Thanks! And I accept your answer.